# Calibration using Camera Calibration Toolbox for Matlab vs OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera, camera-calibration, calibration

I am currently working to calibrate a camera and I tried using both the Caltech [Camera Calibration Toolbox for Matlab](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/)  and [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html). I used the same images for both methods. Even if the error seems to be more or less the same between the two methods, the values don't quite match, especially the distortion coefficients

Matlab results

```
Calibration results after optimization (with uncertainties):

Focal Length:          fc = [ 1475.06776   1474.34956 ] +/- [ 1.30130   1.28283 ]
Principal point:       cc = [ 967.66660   535.09387 ] +/- [ 1.44019   1.23663 ]
Skew:             alpha_c = [ 0.00000 ] +/- [ 0.00000  ]   => angle of pixel axes = 90.00000 +/- 0.00000 degrees
Distortion:            kc = [ 0.06844   -0.15582   0.00049   0.00021  0.00000 ] +/- [ 0.00235   0.00641   0.00028   0.00035  0.00000 ]
Pixel error:          err = [ 0.64754   0.45951 ]

Note: The numerical errors are approximately three times the standard deviations (for reference).
```

and OpenCV results

```
RMS:  0.40118611304523083
Camera matrix:  [[1.46405121e+03 0.00000000e+00 9.64151487e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.46362963e+03 5.35514933e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
Distortion coefficients:  [[ 2.27565390e-01 -1.22470407e+00  3.58771830e-04 -4.77602117e-04
   1.96274452e+00]]
```

I understand that there are differences between the two methods (e.g. corner extraction method) so I shouldn't expect exactly the same results, but the difference still looks significant to me. I tried taking more images of my chessboard tilted at different angles, but the values and the errors don't vary that much.

I am mostly surprised by the difference in the distortion coefficients, as they have orders of difference. If I undistort the chessboard images using the values from the two calibrations, they both look reasonable even if the OpenCV one shows more barrell correction.

Undistorted using Matlab calibration
[image: Undistorted using Matlab calibration]

Undistorted using OpenCV calibration
[image: Undistorted using OpenCV calibration]

My guess is that since the camera does not have too much distortion to start with the two methods converge to different solutions. My question is, is there a way to determine which of these two calibration gives the "best" result? Would they be both acceptable even if they are clearly different?

Comment: OpenCV seems to be worse, the lines on the chessboard corners/borders are less straight. Line straightness is a good metric to measure the quality of the undistortion. Do you know the algorithm used by matlab? If it uses less distortion coefficients, you can limit them in opencv as well. Can you view and compare the detected chessboard corners?

Comment: your data doesn't reach into the corners, where distortion is worst, and the numerical optimization has no support there, which is why it's giving you solutions that fluctuate wildly in the corners. tldr: get data that covers the whole picture.

Comment: @Micka Both models use the same number of coefficients (five), so I don't think the problem is there. I tried to compare the corners visually between the two methods, but if I zoom in the corners I find it hard to determine which is the best one myself as the differences are very subtle

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you! I tried to get as close to the borders as possible but admittedly the images I posted are the closest that I had. Do you know if the OpenCV chessboard detection would work even if the edge squares are partially out of the image?

Comment: imho the last coefficient in matlab looks like it is exactly 0. So maybe Matlab determines the calibration with some coefficients fixed to 0 and chooses the "best" one afterwards (some trade of between using more coefficients vs. getting only slightly better error). Can you try to use opencv calibration with last dist coefficient fixed to 0?

Comment: @Micka thanks a lot. I tried as you said and by fixing the last distortion coefficient to 0 in OpenCV the results between the two methods are very similar now! Turns out that the Matlab calibration toolbox sets that coefficient to 0 by default. Matlab might be right in the sense that the coefficient is not needed, since its correction looks better

Comment: The more distortion coefficients there are, the smaller the reprojection error will be, but the more likely the decrease if from overfitting (so in theory the more data samples you will need). So I guess you could say "start with only n coefficients, then n+1, n+2 etc. and if the decrease in reprojection error isnt good enough anymore: stop"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue thanks to the comments from [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka), so I'll answer my own question in case it can help someone else.

The difference is caused by the fact that Caltech calibration toolbox sets the 5th distortion coefficient, k3, to zero by default. If you want to evaluate it you'll have to activate the proper settings. By forcing k3 to 0 in the OpenCV calibration the results were very similar.